# How can I make "month" columns in Sql?

Tags: sql-server

I've got a set of data that looks something like this (*VERY* simplified):

```
productId    Qty   dateOrdered
---------    ---   -----------
       1       2    10/10/2008
       1       1    11/10/2008
       1       2    10/10/2009
       2       3    10/12/2009
       1       1    10/15/2009
       2       2    11/15/2009
```

Out of this, we're trying to create a query to get something like:

```
productId  Year  Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
---------  ----  --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
        1  2008    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   1   0
        1  2009    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0
        2  2009    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   2   0
```

The way I'm doing this now, I'm doing 12 selects, one for each month, and putting those in temp tables.  I then do a giant join.  Everything works, but this guy is dog slow.

Answer (score 18):

```
select productId, Year(dateOrdered) Year
  ,isnull(sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 1 then Qty end), 0) Jan
  ,isnull(sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 2 then Qty end), 0) Feb 
  ,isnull(sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 3 then Qty end), 0) Mar
  ,isnull(sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 4 then Qty end), 0) Apr
  ,isnull(sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 5 then Qty end), 0) May
  ,isnull(sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 6 then Qty end), 0) Jun
  ,isnull(sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 7 then Qty end), 0) Jul
  ,isnull(sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 8 then Qty end), 0) Aug
  ,isnull(sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 9 then Qty end), 0) Sep
  ,isnull(sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 10 then Qty end), 0) Oct
  ,isnull(sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 11 then Qty end), 0) Nov
  ,isnull(sum(case when month(dateOrdered) = 12 then Qty end), 0) Dec
from Table1
group by productId, Year(dateOrdered)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c844f/6)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT productId, YEAR,
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Product WHERE productId=X.productId AND YEAR=YEAR(dateOrdered) AND MONTH(dateOrdered)=1),0) as 'JAN',
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Product WHERE productId=X.productId AND YEAR=YEAR(dateOrdered) AND MONTH(dateOrdered)=2),0) as 'FEB',
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Product WHERE productId=X.productId AND YEAR=YEAR(dateOrdered) AND MONTH(dateOrdered)=3),0) as 'MAR',
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Product WHERE productId=X.productId AND YEAR=YEAR(dateOrdered) AND MONTH(dateOrdered)=4),0) as 'APR',
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Product WHERE productId=X.productId AND YEAR=YEAR(dateOrdered) AND MONTH(dateOrdered)=5),0) as 'MAY',
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Product WHERE productId=X.productId AND YEAR=YEAR(dateOrdered) AND MONTH(dateOrdered)=6),0) as 'JUN',
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Product WHERE productId=X.productId AND YEAR=YEAR(dateOrdered) AND MONTH(dateOrdered)=7),0) as 'JUL',
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Product WHERE productId=X.productId AND YEAR=YEAR(dateOrdered) AND MONTH(dateOrdered)=8),0) as 'AUG',
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Product WHERE productId=X.productId AND YEAR=YEAR(dateOrdered) AND MONTH(dateOrdered)=9),0) as 'SEP',
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Product WHERE productId=X.productId AND YEAR=YEAR(dateOrdered) AND MONTH(dateOrdered)=10),0) as 'OCT',
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Product WHERE productId=X.productId AND YEAR=YEAR(dateOrdered) AND MONTH(dateOrdered)=11),0) as 'NOV',
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Product WHERE productId=X.productId AND YEAR=YEAR(dateOrdered) AND MONTH(dateOrdered)=12),0) as 'DEC'
FROM (
SELECT productId, YEAR(dateOrdered) AS YEAR FROM Product
GROUP BY YEAR(dateOrdered),ProductId) X
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using Big Query, you can use the following:

```
select *
from UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2015-10-01', '2019-10-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators?hl=fr#generate_date_array

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a Union of your queries rather than temp tables or use the pivot option.

Here's a forum discussion on it:

[Sql Server Forums - Show the row-wise data as column-wise](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=107310)

Comment: UNION...an obvious idea that I somehow missed.  Not sure if that would help, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Yes, it should be more efficient than the temps method. Just set 0 as the value for the select column for the months not participating in the month being queried in each query.

Answer (score 0):

This qualifies as a presentation concern.
Presentation and SQL don't always mix well.

Isolating your presentation logic in the application layer will:

1. save you maintenance time—change your application code, but keep your SQL intact;
2. enable you to more quickly adapt to ephemeral client requirements;
3. give you more satisfaction than fiddling with a cross-tab or pivot-table that maddeningly does almost exactly what you want.

Below is an example of how you might do this in Python (you can use the excellent [pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) module to connect to SQL Server):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import date

dd = defaultdict(int)

# input 
rows = [(1,2,date(2008,10,10)), (1,1,date(2008,11,10)), 
        (1,2,date(2009,10,10)), (2,3,date(2009,10,12)), 
        (1,1,date(2009,10,15)), (2,2,date(2009,11,15))]

for row in rows:
    # row[0] == productId
    # row[1] == Qty
    # row[2] == dateOrdered
    # pyodbc enables referring to column names by name
    dd[(row[2].year, row[2].month, row[0])] += row[1]

presentation_rows = sorted(set((i[0], i[2]) for i in dd.keys()))

for i in presentation_rows:
  print i[1], i[0], 
  for j in range(0,13):
    try:
      print dd[i[0], j, i[1]], 
    except IndexError:
      print 0,
  print

# output
# 1 2008 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0
# 1 2009 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
# 2 2009 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 2 0
```

Answer (score -1):

try this. So this code will select data within certain time range, then convert it to a new column. For example, in my sql code: it selects time range between '2014-10-01' and '2014-10-31' from column 'L_dt', then create a new column called "October". In this way, we can lay out data at different columns originated from one column.

```
select 
sum(case when L_dt between '2014-10-01' and '2014-10-31' then 1 else 0 end) October,
sum(case when L_dt between '2014-11-01' and '2014-11-30' then 1 else 0 end) November,
sum(case when L_dt between '2014-12-01' and '2014-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) December
from Table;
```

If the input looks like: 
   L_dt
2014-10-13
2014-12-21
2014-11-22
2014-10-10

Then the output will be

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| October | November | December |
+---------+----------+----------+
|    2    |    1     |    1     |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Good advice. So this code will select data within certain time range, then convert it to a new column. For example, in my sql code: it selects time range between '2014-10-01' and '2014-10-31' from column 'L_dt', then create a new column called "October". In this way, we can lay out data at different columns originated from one column.

Comment: Oops, don't know why the input and output example don't lay out in the right way...