# SQL Server to show data for each month from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to populate or display the result for each month?

I have a table with four columns

```
Plan    Status    Creation date    Triggers
```

I need to get the results for each plan each month how many triggers count are there. my report should look like this.

```
Plan   Jan   feb   march Apr may  jun  jul  aug   sep   oct  nov  dec  Totaol
 001     2    0     1    1   0    1     1   1    2      3    1    7      21
 002     2    0     1    1   0    1     1   1    2      3    1    7      21
 003     2    0     1    1   0    1     1   1    2      3    1    7      21
```

Could you please help me out how to achieve this results?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a conditional aggregation for this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make "month" columns in Sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296628/how-can-i-make-month-columns-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

```
select
   plan,
   sum(case when datepart(mm,[Creation date]) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan,
   sum(case when datepart(mm,[Creation date]) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Feb,
   ...
   sum(triggers) as Total
from table
where Status = 'SomeStatus'
group by Plan
```

Comment: Thank you scsimon, Instead of triggers count if i want record count for each Plan?

Comment: what do you mean record count? Like 1 for each row?

Comment: what is an example value for status?